# convert 200903 as 03-2009 in sql

Tags: sql

I have a column which is not a date file its a varchar column which store data as '200903', '202306'. I need to format the data into '03-2009' '06-2023' in sql server

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: OT I hope you don't want to UPDATE the column, just SELECT it in the new format. The old format at least *sorts* fine

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(column_name, 4) + '-' + LEFT(column_name, 2) AS formatted_date
FROM your_table_name;
```